# Can we set "allow_url_fopen" "ON" by using the ini_set() function in php

Tags: php

Can we set "allow_url_fopen" "ON" by using ini_set() function  in php

Comment: Have you checked with that settings documentation that it is possible at all to use `ini_set()` function to set it? http://php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: This is usually disabled by hosts as a security precaution. It wouldn't be a very useful precaution if you could override it yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can't, "[allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)" has the changable mode `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`

```
Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf
```

and not by ini_set()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Answer (score 3):

### You can't

[allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) can only be modified from an [ini file or httpd.conf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Answer (score 3):

The `allow_url_fopen` directive belongs to `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` and cannot be set via `ini_set()`

Answer (score 1):

You can only set it in php.ini, not with ini_set.