# Get (file) size, dimensions and mime type from data URI image?

Tags: php, image, canvas, data-uri

I have a wallpaper upload form which automatically generates a thumb out of the visitor selected wallpaper he wishes to upload. This thumb is generated using the canvas and saved as data URI into a text input.

I would like to extract the size that the output file would have if i decoded the data URI ans saved it on the hard drive (before i do it). I would also like to get the mime type (but i guess i can find that by myself), and if possible the image dimensions.

How can i do that please ? Note that i'm not asking how to save a data URI encoded image, just how to extract details about it before saving it.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First, enable `allow_url_fopen` in `php.ini`:

```
; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Then you can read data from data uri directly with `fopen`,`file_get_contents`, etc.

For example, this will make gegerate a `demo.png` and output "hello world":

```
<?php

file_put_contents("demo.png", file_get_contents("data:image/png;base64,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"));

echo file_get_contents("data:text/plaintext;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need to know the file size before saving it. I don't want badly intentionned people to upload huge files.

Comment: `strlen(file_get_contents("..."))` is OK. Besides you can configure `post_max_size` in `php.ini` to limit size of a form post.

Comment: And can i dynamically modify allow_url_fopen using ini_set() if i don't have access to ini file please ?

Comment: No i can't, found the answer.

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573514/cav-we-set-allow-url-fopen-on-by-using-ini-set-function-in-php