# failed to open stream error in simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, file, stream, rss

I am trying to access [RSS live cricket score feed](http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml) of espncricinfo.

My php code is like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");
```

but it is throwing an error like this.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/java8.in/txtWeb/demo.php on line 11
```

looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code actually works** ,but you need to have `allow_url_fopen` to be set **`1`** or **`ON`** to achieve what you are doing.

Check the PHP Manual [`here`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) on how to do that.

### The code...

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");
print_r($xml);
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 ) [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Cricinfo Live Scores [ttl] => 2 [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com [description] => Latest scores from Cricinfo [copyright] => (c)Cricinfo [language] => en-gb [pubDate] => Tue, 04 Feb 2014 19:12:01 +0000 [item] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Bangladesh v Sri Lanka 314/5 * [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/690349.html?CMP=OTC-RSS [description] => Bangladesh v Sri Lanka 314/5 * [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/690349.html ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => South Africa 300/10 v South African Composite XI 24/3 * [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/714095.html?CMP=OTC-RSS [description] => South Africa 300/10 v South African Composite XI 24/3 * [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/714095.html ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Guyana 36/1 * v Windward Islands [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/708797.html?CMP=OTC-RSS [description] => Guyana 36/1 * v Windward Islands [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/708797.html ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Sri Lanka Cricket Women's XI v England Academy Women [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/710579.html?CMP=OTC-RSS [description] => Sri Lanka Cricket Women's XI v England Academy Women [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/710579.html ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Sydney Sixers v Perth Scorchers [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/654097.html?CMP=OTC-RSS [description] => Sydney Sixers v Perth Scorchers [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/654097.html ) ) ) )
```

### The cURL way..

```
<?php
$url = "http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xmlresponse = curl_exec($ch);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: allow_url_fopen is set "on" in php.ini file

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar, Can you try using `cURL` as shown in the answer ?

Comment: tried curl, op is blank. if you will check `var_dump($xml)` it will print `bool(false)`

Answer (score 0):

I found that some shared hosting provider do not support the access of external url although `allow_url_fopen` is set to 1.

Possible solution for problems :

Two solutions are mentioned by Shankar Damodaran in [Above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21561342/1686291)

Another solution or alternate way I found is, [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/ini_set) function.
You can put following code in your php file to modify `php.ini` file properties.

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'on');
```

Comment: 'allow_url_fopen' cannot be set via ini_set function. See here for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573514/can-we-set-allow-url-fopen-on-by-using-the-ini-set-function-in-php

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with SELinux you may need to allow Apache access to the network

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```